# Resolve Push/Pull on branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I've been messing with this for a while and can't seem to resolve this, but I have push and pull pending on my master branch and can't seem to resolve either.

Here is an image, before I go through what I did:

[image]

So, I created the f-Unused_alert_zips branch to do a pull request for 2 deleted files. This was approved and I merged the pull request into master through bitbucket. Then I came back to sourcetree and swithced my active branch back to master. I made a code comment in a file and wanted to just commit/push straight to master but It wouldn't allow it because I needed to pull changes. Apparently I did it wrong because now I'm left with 4 pulls pending and 1 push pending. I've tried and tried but I'm stuck.

I'm very new to git and sourcetree/bitbucket, so I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: What happens when you try to `git pull origin master`?

Comment: Your local master branch was behind 4 commits when you made your change and commit. If you just pull the remote, it should merge into your local master branch ok, then you can push master again. Generally don't commit directly on master. Create feature branch off it and do a pull request into master.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got it resolved after that git command. This already helps me understand the issue a lot more because I was pulling on an earlier commit. And usually we create feature branches, but sometimes we push minor formatting to master and I hadn't swapped branches. Thanks guys!

Comment: yah no prob, yah i usually learn all the git commands first before I move to a nice gui like sourcetree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the commit "Modified code comment with date to show relevance" is authored by you (I guess that's what you've done while waiting for your pull request to be merged)

I also guess that the expected behavior is to see your master's commit on top of origin/master

It is easy to archive with

```
git pull --rebase
```

You may need to resolve conflicts. Don't worry. If you see that the conflicts are hard to resolve you always undo your pull --rebase by issuing `git rebase --abort`

If you want to be on the safer side you can split your `git pull --rebase` into three steps

1. `git fetch --all` It is always safe. It just fetches all new data from remote repositories
2. `git log master --not origin/master` shows commits which you have but which are not present in remote repository
3. `git rebase origin/master` (I assume you are currently on the master branch)

If something goes wrong you can issue `git rebase --abort`